# Ito integral of sign of Brownian motion is a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to solve the following problem (exercise 4.19 from Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance, Vol. 2):

> Let $W(t)$ be a Brownian motion, and define 
>   $$ B(t) = \int_0^t
>  \mathrm{sign}(W(s))dW(s).
> $$ 
>   Show that $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

I have to check four things:

1. $B(0) = 0$.
2. $B(t)$ is a continuous function of $t$.
3. For any three distinct $t_1> t_2> t_3$, $B(t_1) - B(t_2)$ is independent of $B(t_2) - B(t_3)$.
4. For any two distinct $t_1> t_2$, $B(t_1) - B(t_2)$ is distributed as a normal random variable with mean 0 and variance $t_1 - t_2$.

The first requirement, $B(0)=0$ is clear from the definition.

To show that $B(t)$ is continuous, I would start writing the Ito integral for a simple stochastic process:
$$
B(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathrm{sign}(W(t_j))(W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j)),
$$
where $t_0=0, \dots, t_n=t$ are a partition of the interval $[0,t]$.
I would check continuity of $B(t)$ in this way:
$$
\begin{array}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} |B(t+\epsilon) - B(t)| &= 
|\mathrm{sign}(W(t))(W(t + \epsilon) - W(t))| \\
&= |W(t+\epsilon) - W(t)|
&=0,
\end{array}
$$
where the last equality follows by the continuity of $W(t)$.

To check independence of the increments of $B(t)$, I would just write down:
$$
B(t_1) - B(t_2) = \int_{t_2}^{t_1} \mathrm{sign} W(s) dW(s)
$$
and
$$
B(t_2) - B(t_3) = \int_{t_3}^{t_2} \mathrm{sign} W(s) dW(s),
$$
and since the first integral depends only on the history of $W(t)$ between $t_2$ and $t_1$, whereas the second integral depends only on the history of $W(t)$ between $t_3$ and $t_2$, by the independence of the increments of $W(t)$ it follows that also the increments of $B(t)$ are independent random variables.

Finally, to check that the increments of $B(t)$ are normally distributed, I would attempt a computation of the moment generating function of $\Delta(t_2, t_1)=B(t_1) - B(t_2)$.
$$
\begin{array}
M_{\Delta(t_2,t_1)}(u) &= \mathbb{E}[e^{u\Delta(t_2,t_1)}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[e^{u \int_{t_2}^{t_1} \mathrm{sign} W(s) dW(s)} \right],
\end{array}
$$
where the expectation is done among all possible paths of $W(s)$ between $t_2$ and $t_1$.

My question is: are my proofs of the first three points correct? How can I prove the fourth one?

Edit: related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460294/ito-integral-of-sign-function-is-a-brownian-motion), but not exactly the same as mine (I am asking if I can prove the normality of the increments by explicitly computing a moment generating function, and if the other three points of the exercise are correctly proven).

Answer (score 3):

$B(t)$ is a continuous local martingale with $B(0)=0$ and quadratic variation process given by
$$
[B(t)]=\int_0^t [\operatorname{sgn}(W(s))]^2\,ds=\int_0^t 1\{W(s)\ne 0\}\,ds=t \quad\text{a.s.}
$$
Therefore, $B(t)$ is a standard BM by [Levy's characterisation theorem](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/).